# How to join two queries?

Tags: sql

I have 2 separate queries and want to `join` them and don't know how to. If I run the below I get the error:

> The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns.

How do I `join` them successfully?

**first query**

```
SELECT

hardware_info.id as ComputerID,
software_info.OSPlatform as OperatingSystemName,
software_info.OSVersion as OSVersion,
agent_info.AgentName as DeviceName,
hardware_info.last_modified as LastUpdate,
software_info.AD_MachineOUPath as NTDomainName,
software_info.AD_UserOUPath as AD_Site,
hardware_info.ComputerManufacturer as Manufacturer,
hardware_info.MachineModel as Model,
hardware_info.CPUCount as NoOfCPUs,
software_info.OSPlatform as OperatingSystemName,
hardware_info.MachineSerialno as SerialNumber,
hardware_info.CPUIDString as CPUDescription,
hardware_info.CPUSpeed as MaxClockSpeed,
hardware_info.PrimaryMACAddress as PhysicalAddress,
hardware_info.PhysicalMemorySize as Memory    

FROM
agent_info,
hardware_info,
software_info,
machine_tracking_info,
installed_software_titles     
WHERE
agent_info.heartbeat_record_id = hardware_info.agent_info_record_id limit 10
```

**SAMPLE RESULT**

```
ComputerID 1    
OperatingSystemName 116
OSVersion 1584  
DeviceName USALVWAM1    
LastUpdate 2016-07-08 04:27:01  
NTDomainName Servers\from New Computers
AD_Site Global-Users\US\CS  
Manufacturer    VMware, Inc.    
Model   GenericPC
NoOfCPUs    1   
OperatingSystemName SerialNumber VMware-42 04 90 30 1d a2 bc dc-69 a6 eb    47  68 76 b1 3b    
CPUDescription  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz
MaxClockSpeed   2500000000  
PhysicalAddress 00:50:56:84:40:50
Memory 4294967296

**second query**
SELECT 
enum_value as osplatform 
FROM
software_info
INNER JOIN
    enum_osplatform ON software_info.OSPlatform = enum_osplatform.enum_key

**SAMPLE RESULT**

osplatform windows 2012 r2
```

Comment: Add sample result from the two queries, and then show us the combined result.

Comment: your second select query is wrong correct it.

Comment: Also, your first query has only 1 join condition, but 5 tables are joined (implicitly). On purpose?!? Tip of today: switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax - easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: how does `software_info` join to the other tables?

Comment: hi matt I am not sure what you mean. I have edited my main posts with both scripts and both samples that work. I just need to join them.

Comment: Hi meena, the second query does work so i am not sure what you mean?

Comment: The latest edit wrecked the formatting. Very hard to read now...

Comment: ok corrected, hopefully ok now.

Answer (score 2):

Number field in tow query must be equal.

try like this

```
 SELECT 
    hardware_info.id as ComputerID,
    agent_info.AgentName as DeviceName,
    hardware_info.last_modified as LastUpdate,
    software_info.AD_MachineOUPath as NTDomainName,
    software_info.AD_UserOUPath as AD_Site,
    hardware_info.ComputerManufacturer as Manufacturer,
    hardware_info.MachineModel as Model,
    hardware_info.CPUCount as NoOfCPUs,         
    hardware_info.MachineSerialno as SerialNumber,
    hardware_info.CPUIDString as CPUDescription,
    hardware_info.CPUSpeed as MaxClockSpeed,
    hardware_info.PrimaryMACAddress as PhysicalAddress,
    hardware_info.PhysicalMemorySize as Memory, 
    software_info.OSVersion ,
    software_info.OSPlatform as OperatingSystemName,
    null      
FROM
    agent_info,
    hardware_info,
    software_info,
    machine_tracking_info,
    installed_software_titles     
WHERE
    agent_info.heartbeat_record_id = hardware_info.agent_info_record_id

union

SELECT 
    null as ComputerID,
    null as DeviceName,
    null as LastUpdate,
    null as NTDomainName,
    null as AD_Site,
    null as Manufacturer,
    null as Model,
    null as NoOfCPUs,           
    null as SerialNumber,
    null as CPUDescription,
    null as MaxClockSpeed,
    null as PhysicalAddress,
    null as Memory,
    null as OSVersion,
     osplatform ,enum_value
FROM
    software_info
INNER JOIN
    enum_osplatform ON software_info.OSPlatform = enum_osplatform.enum_key
```

Comment: Ashkufaraz, thanks but i get the same error with yours.

Comment: when i execute now it just hangs? I have edited and posted both scripts and sample results in my main post. I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

As above you can `UNION` and use `NULL`'s in the second part.

I have approached it differently. Just need to fill in the XXX when you provide the information.

```
SELECT
h.id AS ComputerID,
a.AgentName AS DeviceName,
h.last_modified AS LastUpdate,
s.AD_MachineOUPath AS NTDomainName,
s.AD_UserOUPath AS AD_Site,
h.ComputerManufacturer AS Manufacturer,
h.MachineModel AS Model,
h.CPUCount AS NoOfCPUs,
s.OSPlatform AS OperatingSystemName,
h.MachineSerialno AS SerialNumber,
h.CPUIDString AS CPUDescription,
h.CPUSpeed AS MaxClockSpeed,
h.PrimaryMACAddress AS PhysicalAddress,
h.PhysicalMemorySize AS Memory, 
s.OSVersion,
enum_value as OSPlatform
FROM agent_info a
INNER JOIN hardware_info h ON a.heartbeat_record_id = h.agent_info_record_id 
INNER JOIN software_info s ON a.heartbeat_record_id = s.agent_info_record_id
INNER JOIN enum_osplatform e ON s.OSPlatform = e.enum_key
```

Comment: thanks Matt. I am not sure what you mean abotu filling in the X's?

Comment: @sql1 how does the software info table join to the other tables

Comment: sorry matt not sure what you mean. All i know is the 2nd query above gets me that information.  Is there a way to find out?

Comment: You need to read more on SQL and get a better understanding of basic concepts.

Comment: thanks Matt thats great. I edited it as above and figured out the XXX's. My next issue is the OSVersion column is showing as numbers e.g 1584 and not the correct value e.g 10.10. How do i figure that?